# how to call back in asynchronous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure

Basically, my application is a PhoneGap app with windows azure service, I have a problem with callback method with javascript.Please check the code below.

```
checkeventsRegistration = function (azureEid,regid,callback) {
  alert(azureEid + " <> " + regid);
  var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mobbacktest.azure-mobile.net/', 'RvahPxHKoEsGiLdlCYZpHBllvSVQxl66');
  reglog = client.getTable('registrationlog');
  query = reglog.where({ eventid: azureEid, regid: regid });

  query.read().done(function (log)
  {
    alert("Log:" + log.length);
  });
  callback(log.length);
};
```

and i will call this function as below.

```
checkeventsRegistration(eid, regid, savenum);
```

My issue is this callback method is firing before the `query().read()`.

Comment: Insert the call into the anonym function declared in done()

Comment: move the `callback` call inside the `query.read().done(...)` callback.

Comment: query.read().done(function (log)
{
    alert("Log:" + log.length);
 callback(log.length);};

});

Comment: i tried like that before.but no luck.

Comment: what is the error which occured when you tried to call callback inside done?

Comment: thanx osama i solved it..thank you again

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `callback` in your outer function is to perform some action when the asynchronous operation is done, therefore you should be calling it from inside the `done` method.

```
query.read().done(function (log){
    alert("Log:" + log.length);
    callback(log.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query.read().done(function (log)
{
    alert("Log:" + log.length);
    callback(log.length);

});
```

as the read function is a sync, the execution will go to the next line directly without waiting for the call result.
on the other hand, .done() accepts two call, the first one onSuccess, and the second is the onError.
Hence, you should call your callback function in done(function(){callback();})

Incase it was not worked, send the error, may be you need to JSON.stringfy(log) before making your process.

Comment: add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code is different from the code in the question, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.